# Django REST Framework after PUT/PATCH action

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to make some actions after an api's PUT/PATCH process is completed.

My API updates some values of one Model but after these Updates I want to Update another Model values taking  the info sent of the API.

For Example:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Model2(models.Model):
    val = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

I have this models, so, my API updates Model1.qty value with a PATCH call. Then I want to Update the Model2.val value with the data of the PATCH call to my API that actually is equals to Model1.qty value

I dont know exactly how to do this but I think I should Override the "update" method.

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...??
def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...??
```

Any Ideas?

**NOTE** Im using HyperlinkedModelSerializers, ModelViewSets and Routers to make my API works.

Answer (score 1):

The `post_save` method on views exists exactly for this reason. The Django REST Framework documentation [doesn't cover it well](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#genericapiview), but it is a hook that is called with two arguments, `obj` (the object that was saved) and `created` (True for POST/PUT-as-create, False for PUT-as-update/PATCH).

You can get access to the sent data with `self.request.DATA`, which should allow you to modify saved objects to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

`post_save` as mentioned before is now (>2.x) outdated (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/). The new functions to hook on generic views are:

```
perform_create(self, serializer)
perform_update(self, serializer)
perform_destroy(self, instance)
```